# aiohttp の response からステータスコードを取得する方法

Tags: python

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
  async with session.get(url) as response:
```

の response から status_code を取得するのはどうすればいいんでしょうか

```
response = request.get(url)
```

とは型が違うみたいで `response.status_code` が存在しないといわれます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純に名前が `status_code` ではなく `status` でしょうね。

[Client Reference - aiohttp 3.6.2 documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html)

> ```
> import aiohttp
> import asyncio
>
> async def fetch(client):
>     async with client.get('http://python.org') as resp:
>         assert resp.status == 200
>         return await resp.text()
>
> async def main():
>     async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
>         html = await fetch(client)
>         print(html)
>
> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
> loop.run_until_complete(main())
> ```

Comment: ありがとうございます！　あとモジュールのリファレンスドキュメントの場所がわからなかったので今度からドキュメントを読んでみます。